# Where can I store my connection string given by the user in c#?

Tags: c#, connection-string, dbcontext, setup-project

I create a Windows service and a setup project. Actually, the connection string of my DbContext is in my project .config but the user can see the content of the .config and modify it so where can store my connection string ?

**IMPORTANT** : I get the from the user interface during the installation of my project.

Comment: We use a configuration file to change the connection string at the later stage without changing the ode. So, if you don't want to allow a user to view the content, encrypt the connection string and decrypt in code where you are using.

Comment: @Rafaqat Ali Ok but if I encrypt mu connection string finally when I will do my request I will have to decrypt the connection string before the request and encrypt it magasin after ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [encrypt the configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information) so user will not be able to see the connection details.
Another option is storing it in key vault [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Note that a determined competent attacker will still be able to obtain the credentials - Ideally you would connect using Windows Integrated Security so no password is stored in the first place. If you want to stop the user being able to access SQL directly, then you need to place a layer inbetween (i.e. an API that your program calls to perform database access on its request)